# Basic measure theory question. Need help seeing why these sets should be the same.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

When checking if a set is measurable, it's often written in a complicated way as a countable intersection such as

$$\{x \in E \mid f(x)\ge c\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \{x \in E \mid f(x) > c - 1/k\}$$

or a union such as

$$\{x \in E \mid f(x) > c\}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{x \in E \mid f(x)\ge c + 1/k\}$$

and then we prove what we're proving by using properties possessed by the sets on the right.

I can follow the logic used in the proofs but how did we think of writing the sets on the left as those on the right in the first place? Also, I'm not entirely convinced if these equalities actually hold. How do I prove they're true? Do I need to be able to just see that they're true? If yes, how do I build the intuition to do so. I guess what I want to know is is there a trick where I can just see in my head that the sets on the right should give me what's on the left?

Another case of interest to me comes up when proving $f + g$ is measurable.

Here, if we assume $f(x) + g(x) < c$ (why not work with > c in this case also?), then $f(x)<c - g(x)$ and we first used the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to write $f(x) < q < c-g(x)$. Then,

$$\{x \in E \mid f(x)+g(x) < c\}=\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{x \in E \mid g(x)< c-q\} \cap \{x \in E \mid f(x)<q\}.$$

In this example, I'm just not able to visualize that the set on the right is equal to that on the left. How do I see that they're equal?

Comment: In general, showing that one set is equal to another requires showing that every element of one set must be an element of the other, and vice versa. So, in your first example, if $f(x) \ge c$ then $f(x)\ge c-1/k$  for every k, so every $x$ with the first property is in every set on the right hand side, so in their intersection. Also, if $f(x)<c$ then there is a k such that $\frac{1}{k} < c - f(x)$ and then $f(x)$ is not in the $k^{th}$ set on the right, so not in their intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motivation comes from viewing membership in a union and intersection as exists and forall statements respectively.

For your first example, for $z\in E$
$$
\begin{align*}
&z\in\{x \in E \mid f(x)\geq c\}\\
&\iff f(z) \geq c \\
&\iff \forall k\in\mathbb{N}, f(z) > c-\frac{1}{k}\\
&\iff \forall k\in\mathbb{N}, z\in\{x\in E: f(x) > c-\frac{1}{k}\}\\
&\iff z\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \{x \in E \mid f(x) > c - 1/k\}\\
\end{align*}
$$
You may prove similar things for the other two examples you give. Thus, my trick is visualize your union as a sort of exists, and your intersect as a sort of forall

Now for proving the third example, it suffices to show $$f(z) + g(z) < c \iff \exists q\in\mathbb{Q} \text{ s.t } g(z) < c-q \text{ and } f(z)<q$$
The right to left direction is showed using inequality properties, and the other direction is showed using the density, i.e. if $f(z)<c-g(z)$ there is a $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ between them. Thus, you may use this iff to talk about the two sets in your third equality